# ModelState create List string with Key + ErrorMessage. (LINQ)

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, ienumerable, modelstate

I Want to obtain something like this:

' myKey: errorMessage '

Now i've a list with all the ModelState errors:

```
List<String> modelStateErrors2 = ModelState.Keys.SelectMany(key => this.ModelState[key].Errors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage).ToList();
```

But need to add the key in the begin of the string.

It is possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to move the `Select()` inside the `SelectMany()` so it can close over the `key`:

```
ModelState.Keys.SelectMany(key => this.ModelState[key].Errors.Select(x => key + ": " + x.ErrorMessage));
```

This would be simpler as a query comprehension:

```
from kvp in ModelState
from e in kvp.Value.Errors
select kvp.Key + ": " + e.ErrorMessage
```

Comment: @EzequielLeiva: You're welcome! BTW, `kvp` stands for `KeyValuePair`.

Comment: The LINQ query is nice!